# Does it make sense to split a large table into smaller ones to reduce the number of rows (not columns)?

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning

I have a massive database with lots of sentences in different languages.

Example:

```
SENTENCE MODEL
id     123
lang   "en"
text   "The fox is out and about"
```

Now let's say I have trillions of trillions of sentences in this table, in all kinds of different languages. However, I only ever need to query this table for a single language at a time: I will either be searching through *just German sentences*, or *just French sentences*, and so on.

Does it make sense to put these into one big table nonetheless, or am I sacrificing performance considerably here? From a coding perspective, it would be much easier to have it all in one table. Or is there anything else that you would recommend here that I am not aware of?

Comment: Does the app pick the table?  Even so, the savings is minimal.  Does your query include `WHERE lang = 'fr'`?  and the index (preferably the PK) _start with_ `lang`?

Comment: If you are relying on fulltext search, you can't use a fulltext index and an index on the `lang` column in the same table reference. So it would make sense to split the table into one table for each language. But I'm making an assumption about how you are querying. In general, **you can't choose which optimization strategy is best until you evaluate it against your specific queries.**